# Consequence of epimorphism from Noetherian $R$-module

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, artinian

Let $R,S$ be a commutative rings with $1_R,1_S$ respectively. In the most commutative algebra one can find the following proposition.

> **Proposition.** Let $φ:R\twoheadrightarrow S$ be a ring epimorphism. Then, if $R$ is Noetherian/Artinian, $S$ is also Noetherian/Artinian.

I was wondering if this is still valid for $R$-modules.

> *That is, let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1_R$, $M,N$ two $R$-modules and $φ:M \twoheadrightarrow N$ a module epimorphism. If $R$-module $M$ is Noetherian/Artinian, then $R$-module $N$ is Noetherian/Artinian.*

*Proof.* Trying to follow the steps of the proposition above, we consider an arbitrary ascending chain of $R$-submodules of $N$,
$$N_1\subseteq N_2 \subseteq N_3 \subseteq \dotsb.$$
We set $M_i=φ^{-1}(N_i),\ \forall i=1,2,3,\dots.$ The preimage of $R$-module is [again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557395/preimage-of-a-module-under-a-module-homomorphism-is-a-submodule) an $R$-module. So, taking the preimages on the chain above, we can constract the ascending chain of $R$-submodules of $M$,
$$M_1\subseteq M_2 \subseteq M_3 \subseteq \dotsb.$$
But $M$ is Noetherian $R$-module, so there is an index $m\in \Bbb Z^+$ s.t.
\begin{alignat*}{2}
M_m \quad = & \quad M_k,\ &&  \forall k\geq m \iff\\
φ^{-1} (N_m) \quad = & \quad φ^{-1} (N_k),\ && \forall k\geq m \implies \\
φ(φ^{-1} (N_m)) \quad = & \quad φ(φ^{-1} (N_k)),\ && \forall k\geq m \iff \\
N_m \quad = & \quad N_k,\ && \forall k\geq m
\end{alignat*}
and $``\iff"$ is valid because $φ$ is surjective.

***Is this proof correct and complete?***

Thank you.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's correct.

I guess most commutative algebra courses/books show that:

> **Proposition.**
>   If $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of $R$-modules, then:
>
> $M$ is artinian/noetherian iff $M',M''$ are artinian/noetherian.

So you might want to try proving this result.

Your proposition is the special case $0 \rightarrow \ker\varphi \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0$.

Note that being an epimorphism is equivalent to being surjective for modules, but this is not the case for rings, as $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ is epi - I'm not sure if your version for ring epimorphisms is true, although I don't have a counter-example on hand.

Comment: I think for *ring* epimorphisms the Noetherianity does not behave  well. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/110443/23950).

Comment: Btw, when I read the question I thought the OP refers to ring epimorphisms in the category of commutative rings.

Comment: Yes, I thought of commutative rings in my asnwer as well.